# Connecting two points with existing polylines

Tags: routing

I have two layers, one with the points I want to connect and one with the existing streets. Now I want to find a route along those polylines to connect my two points. I didn't find any tools yet. How can I do this? I'm using QGIS 3.0
If it is possible I would also like to use only the streets who are suitable for cars for example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use network analysis tools. Here is some [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html). To use streets only suitable for cars, if there is an attribute that defines suitability, that attribute can be used otherwise you have to extract only those streets and make a new layer.